# 'npm run dev' and 'npm run build prod' not producing the same output

Tags: css, npm, webpack, vue.js

I'm developing a progressive web app using Vue.js.

While I'm developing I use the command `npm run dev` to start the local server which serves the files on http://localhost:8080/. When I want to build for production I use `npm run build prod` which generates the output files in `project\dist`. I then take those files and copy them onto an ISS which is configured to work with single-page applications. All good so far.

I noticed some differences in the way the app looks (css) between the dev and prod build. First I thought this might be because of a client side cache, but after several tries to clean the cache and no-cache loading I'm sure that caching is not the issue here. The output really is different.

To be honest, I'm not sure if there is anything else different besides a few minor css parts. I was thinking what might be the issue, one of the things I noticed that could be the cause is that I use single file components in vue with scoped css (`*.scoped.vue.css` file names). I guess there could be an issue combining the different files into a single one?

It might be noted that I'm quite a newby when it comes to npm, webpack and all the other involved technologies. If you want to take a look at the configuration, you can find my current working branch build configurations [here](https://github.com/tobiaswuerth/mux-www/tree/6d960cea4dd7bc3bfffd0d1b7936e5298519ba66/build).

Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? Having the same issue at the moment

Comment: @ThomasvanBroekhoven sadly no

Comment: @TobiasWürth Ok thanks. I did kind of solve it by giving the `<template>` an id and include that in scss. Also I applied an `!important` to a general style I was forced to override. It might not be the cleanest solution, but it solves the problems for now.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when using single file components. The issue indeed seems to be that when you run `npm run build` it will generate one single css file without the guarantee that the styling will be applied in the same order, causing some property values to be ignored. I 'fixed' it by adding `!important` to the properties that weren't matching up in the final build. There's probably a better way to handle this, but I must admit I too am quite a newby.

Answer (score 0):

The order of how styles are applied while `npm run build` matters, and is to my knowledge out of (y)our control. To get rid of conflicts, when using `Vue.js`, you may want to `scope` your styles.

In every `*.vue` file within your project, replace

```
<style>
...
</style>
```

With

```
<style scoped>
...
</style>
```

Comment: The styles are already scoped, the filename ending `*.scoped.vue.css` implies that